# Trouble with spacing in between Bootstrap rows

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm currently developing my resume website with bootstrap and am having a bit of trouble with getting my rows to mesh and display right.

I know why the problem is occurring (my education module is extending the height of the row too far), but I'm not sure how to fix it.

As of now, I have two rows: the top row is my Skills and Education row, while the bottom is my experience and a blank module.

I've tried nesting rows (maybe I didn't implement it correctly?), as well as messing with fluidity, responsiveness, etc.

Is it something easy that I'm just overthinking?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4g6gt.jpg

Comment: Can you share your markup, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have two columns in a row, and then nest the two sections in the left column.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/5610/)

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span8">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <!--Skills-->
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
     <!--Experience-->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="span4">
    <!--Education-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your **CSS** code

```
#education{
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: I think it might behave better if you use the bootstrap markup to control positioning, but this does solve the problem.